# How to retrieve specific object information from a spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner

I am dealing with some spinners in my android app and on button click I would like to get specific object information. I am aware of `mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();` but that prints out whatever my Objects `toString();` method is. Lets say I want to `getCredits();` from my `Course` object that is currently selected on a spinner. How would I go about it?

here is to give you an idea what I am trying to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < allSpinners.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(allSpinners.get(i).getSelectedItem().toString());

        }
```

I need to get every credit from all spinners in the list.
This code instead of `System.out.println();` needs to get the credits of `Course` object through a `getCredits();` method and add them up together `+=` but I am not sure how to get to the object in the list of spinners.

Edit: Sorry for being unclear. Each spinner holds around 300 objects that are being pulled from an ArrayList that is populated through a TreeMap which takes objects from a text file

Comment: Get the spinner position and then do with the position based action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spinner list is **always** filled with strings provided by its adapter, so when selecting an item from the spinner, you can't expect something other than just a string; so you need some way to utilize this string to get your custom object ("Course" in your example); a `switch` statement is way of doing it by taking this `String` 'course name' returned from `mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();` , and then on each `switch case` instantiate a `Course` object, and do whatever you want on it like in your example `getCredits();`

If you're triggering a listener, the same can apply

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch(position) // switch on item position in adapter

        String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        switch(selection) // switch on item String
    }
}
```

should you need any further help, I will be full of welcome!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The problem is that each spinner hold around 300 Objects of type Course that are being read from a text file and fed into a TreeMap<String, Course> and then fed into an ArrayList<Coruse> to populate the spinners. So I am not sure if a Switch statement will be sufficient for so many objects.

Comment: could you get the course object directly from your TreeMap with the course name as the key?

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can do like this

```
    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    //Do what you want
                    break;

                case 1:
                    //Do what you want
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reminder everyone, turns out `courseMap.get(allSpinners.get(i).getSelectedItem().toString()).getCredits();` is how I should go about it. All of that within a for loop where `i < allSpinner.size();` that being the array of Spinners